# Swagger Authentication using Annotation

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am trying to have a basic Auth in my swagger ui.I am using Swagger 2.0.5 as a maven library.Using SwaggerConfig class to create docket Api and other configuration.

`

```
public class SwaggerConfig {

    /**
     * Every Docket bean is picked up by the swagger-mvc framework - allowing for multiple
     * swagger groups i.e. same code base multiple swagger resource listings.
     */

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        AuthorizationScope[] authScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
        authScopes[0] = new AuthorizationScopeBuilder()
                .scope("")
                .build();

        SecurityReference securityReference = SecurityReference.builder()
                .reference("basicAuth")
                .scopes(authScopes)
                .build();

        ArrayList<SecurityReference> reference = new ArrayList<SecurityReference>(1);
        reference.add(securityReference);


        ArrayList<SecurityContext> securityContexts = new ArrayList<SecurityContext>(1);
        securityContexts.add(SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(reference).build());

        ArrayList<SecurityScheme> auth = new ArrayList<SecurityScheme>(1);
        auth.add(new BasicAuth("basicAuth"));

        Documentation Doc = new DocumentationBuilder().basePath("/swagger-ui.html").build();

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .securitySchemes(auth)
                .securityContexts(securityContexts)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.toyota.tme.consumerapi.rest"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
                }

  /*  @Bean
    public Docket customDocket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/v1/.*"))
                .build();
    }*/

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {


        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Consumer API")
                .description("Azure based Consumer API.")
                .contact("CarIT")
                .build();
    }
}`
```

My Issue is,I am using authorization annotatation in my rest service to enable Basic Auth.

```
    @Api(value = "/ping", tags = "1.Ping", description = "API",authorizations = {@Authorization(value="basicAuth")})
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ping {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    @RequestMapping(path = "/ping", method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Ping service", httpMethod = "GET", response = String.class,
            produces = "text/html", notes = "ping service",authorizations = {@Authorization(value="basicAuth")})
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = String.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad request"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 409, message = "Conflict"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 503, message = "Dependent System(s) are unavailable"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Unknown server Error occurred")})
    public ResponseEntity<String> ping() {
        this.logger.info("springframework api :Ping Request received for ConsumerAPI");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ApplicationConstants.Ping, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

But this code is not working.I am not able to see any authorization asked by Swagger.Please need a help in this

Answer (score 0):

Same for me. Solved this by moving the value authorizations from Api to ApiOperation annotation. Not beautiful but working.